# iAd warning message

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have implemented the following code

```
-(void)initializeiAd
    {

        ADBannerView *bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        bannerView.delegate = self;
        bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bannerView.frame.size.width, bannerView.frame.size.height);
        [self addSubview:bannerView];

    }
```

I see the banner well, but I am getting error message 
WARNING A banner view (0x8560e20) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view.

I wonder why.
 Any ideas? I looked at some KB here but none of them explain it, my view is sub view of another view, I see the AD banner on the screen, the test runs ok.
Should I just ignore such message

Comment: Perhaps there's a transparent UIView on top of the ADBannerView?

Comment: I am loading 2 views, the ADBannerView loading last as subview.

Answer (score 0):

Adbanners have predetermined size constraints that you should be using. Give this a try:

```
bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;    

bannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(bannerView.frame, 0, 0);
```